# How can I make a library framework available in Xcode 6 on OS X 10.10?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, juce, aubio

I had this working on OS X 10.9.

I've imported a library framework (aubio) to the 10.10 SDK folder: 
 / Applications ▸ Xcode.app ▸ Contents ▸ Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ MacOSX.platform ▸ Developer ▸ SDKs ▸ MacOSX10.10.sdk ▸ System ▸ Library ▸ Frameworks

It shows up in Xcode. But when I go to compile the project it tells me it can't find the header.

[image]

So I have to import the framework, manually each time the project gets resaved (which can sometimes be quite often when using the [Introjucer](http://www.juce.com/learn/introjucer)).   This then shows two copies of the framework. I am then able to use the import statement and build the project.

[image]

How can I get the framework to be initially recognised by Xcode so that I can compile the project without re-importing it each time?

Answer (score 0):

in the Introjucer go to your build-config and scroll down to "Extra Frameworks". Insert the name of the framework there. (at the picture is an iOS build config, but it's the same for OSX.)

TIP: you should check the JUCE forum: http://www.juce.com/forum
There are a lot of people with advanced JUCE-knowlege.

[image: Introjucer - add framework on OSX]

Comment: Thanks, but I already have that setting in place - the problem is on the Xcode side, when it tries to find the framework it cant and so I have to re-import it again even though its visible in the list of frameworks.

Comment: Is the Framework in a default directory? From the Apple developer info page: **The standard locations for frameworks are the /System/Library/Frameworks directory and the /Library/Frameworks directory on the local system**. 
It seems you can not set the framework search path for the project from the Introjucer.

Apple manual "Including Frameworks":
(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html)

Comment: I have tried those locations too.. still does not work for me. I had it set up working on Mountain Lion, but since the move to Yosemite I have to import it again each time...